# High data egress when inserting to Azure Table Storage

Tags: azure-table-storage

I'm seeing high Data Egress from Table Storage while *Inserting* a large amount of data into it. Why?

There are several million Insert calls being made from my .Net application using CloudTable.Execute() passing in an Insert table operation.

The .Net application is in AWS Sydney, and I'm inserting to Azure Table Sydney.

I'm connecting to the table just once with this code:

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(StorageConnString);

CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("mytablename");

table.CreateIfNotExists();
```

And then looping over the next section to push the data into Table Storage:

```
foreach (Object obj in myList)
{
    TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.Insert(obj);
    table.Execute(insertOperation);
}
```

I'd expect (and I can see) significant data ingress levels, which is great, but I don't know why the egress numbers are so large. The image below is the last 24 hours of data against the Table account, and the activity is purely write - there are no reads happening on this account at this stage.
[24 hours Table Storage Data Ingress & Egress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgudO.png)

Obviously the data cost for this is not significant - I'm more asking out of curiosity because I've searched high and low on stack overflow and docs.microsoft but can't find any explanation for the high egress.

Does anyone know what might be causing the high egress?

Thanks.

Comment: You can enable storage analytics on the storage account to check the operation history against your table.

Comment: Thanks - I'll try analytics.I thought I had found the solution with setting false to not echo content in "TableOperation.Insert(obj, false);" but that didn't seem to affect Data Egress.

Comment: I'm curious, the egress you're seeing could be possibly caused by replication. do you have any specific redundancy setup for the table/storage account ?

Comment: At the time it was only set to local redundancy.

Comment: Have a look where the Function executables and logs are stored - this is in a container within Table Storage called 'File Shares'.  Depending on your logging strategy this may result in many writes which in turn could result in data egress if replication is setup.